# Creating a Directory on a Server (On the same LAN with your PC) using C# (Winform Application)

Tags: c#

I tried (from Windows 11) to create a Directory on a Windows 2016 Server sitting on my LAN. The Directory "Archives" and its subdirectory "BN" are already existing and had granted "EVERYONE" Full Permission to read/write in them. But when I tried to create a subfolder under "BN" using the command

```
try
 {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"\\WIN-FM8PGNEC4OF\Archives\BN\A1");
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
```

i kept getting the exception error "The user name or password is incorrect."
How do I include the Server's user login credentials in the code above, or are there other ways of creating a folder in a server from a C# or even using Command Prompt (gets the same error after trying `mkdir \\WIN-FM8PGNEC4OF\Archives\BN\A1`) ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Network credentials

```
NetworkCredential theNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
CredentialCache theNetcache = new CredentialCache();
theNetCache.Add(@"\\computer", theNetworkCredential, "Basic", theNetworkCredential);
//then do whatever, such as creating folders:
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"\\WIN-FM8PGNEC4OF\Archives\BN\A1");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried using the network credentials as you suggested in the following way

```
NetworkCredential theNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential("user@myorg.com", "**********", "myorg.com");
CredentialCache theNetcache = new CredentialCache();
theNetcache.Add(new Uri(@"\\CACEDGE"), "Basic", theNetworkCredential);
try
{
 Directory.CreateDirectory(@"\\CACEDGE\Archives\BN\A1");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```
It was still giving me the same error. 
Could it be possible I didn't do exactly (syntax wise) like you suggested? help

Comment: Your solution worked. I just had to replace the Computer Name (WIN-FM8PGNEC4OF) with its ip address. You're the best

Comment: @YassirYahaya, not problem. Glad I could help